# Creating Splash Screen in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, uiviewcontroller, splash-screen

I am trying to create my first simple application.

I want to have two views: first one should stay for couple of seconds and then it should be replaced by second one.

Answer (score 2):

When you start a new project in XCode, it creates a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` for you. This is the splash screen that is shown before you app is loaded.

Comment: if i setup LaunchScreen for launchScreen and in the beginning of my app the LaunchScreen stays and nothing changes

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. You put something in your LaunchScreen.storyboard in interface builder and when your app launches it never makes it past the launch screen?